# Вводное слово в присоединительном обороте

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь нужно выделить запятыми весь оборот "например трансмиссии"
Специальная конструкция предлагаемого устройства позволяет решать задачи по снижению динамических нагрузок при передаче крутящего момента, устранению автоколебаний, например трансмиссии (,) за счет управляемой жесткости упругого элемента компенсатора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аленка, Вы и здесь правы, потому что в правиле сказано, что если пояснительный оборот начинается с вводного слова, то вводное слово от оборота не отделяется запятой, то есть обособляется вся конструкция (например трансмиссии, в частности трансмиссии и т.п.)

Comment: Да, мы здесь это уже как-то обсуждали, но я не смогла найти этот вопрос в истории...